# Guice Dependency Injection Not Working in Maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am using the `sisu-maven-plugin` to generate a configuration file for a maven plugin I am writing.  I checked the `javax.inject.Named` file it creates in the META-INF folder of my maven plugin's jar, and this file has all the classes I have annotated with the `@Named` and `@Singleton` (both annotations on each component) listed in it.  Those classes are the only thing listed in the config file.  I then have a single constructor annotated in my mojo with the `@Inject` annotation.  When I try to use my plugin in a small test app, I get a guice error saying "Could not find suitable constructor".

I tried downloading the example plugin provided at http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/core-integration-testing/trunk/core-it-suite/src/test/resources/mng-5382/ but I received the same error.  So my question is this: has anyone successfully gotten guice dependency injection working in a maven plugin?  If so, what did you have to do?

Also, I am using maven 3.0.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched to maven 3.2.1, and the dependency injection worked as expected.

Comment: I did some more digging and found that JSR-330 annotations were made available in maven plugins starting with maven version 3.1.0